# Предложения, критика по коду) Программа вычисления BMI

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

я начинаю изучать плюсы, составил программу вычисления BMI, хотел бы услышать вашу критику, рекомендации по коду. Использую книгу Пола и Харви Дейтела.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
// программа вычисления BMI
int main ()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    double bmi, weight, height;

    std::cout << "Введите ваш рост (в сантиметрах): \n";
    std::cin >> height;
    height = height / 100;
    std::cout << "Введите ваш вес: \n";
    std::cin >> weight;

    bmi = weight / (height * height);
    
    std::cout << "Ваш bmi составляет: " << bmi << std::endl;

    if (bmi < 18.5)
        std::cout << "Вес ниже нормы.";
    if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9)
        std::cout << "Вес в норме.";
    if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 29.9)
        std::cout << "Вес в избытке.";
    if (bmi > 30)
        std::cout << "Тучный вес.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: из явных ошибок: предлагаю задуматься, что будет, если bmi получится, например, `24.94`…

Comment: Можно просто записать таблицу границ весов и выводов, и проверять в цикле.